# Passing empty IEnumerable<> to constructor

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Based on the current content in the database two things happen.

1. If the table buildingDefine is not empty, pass this table to the constructor.
2. else pass and empty table of buildingDefine to the constructor.

Here is my check for towards the database:

```
        //Is there content in buildingDefineTable?
if (!_bDefine.Any())
{
    int currentBuildingId = ((BuildingTable)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Id;

    var currentBool = from bla in _building
                        where bla.Id == currentBuildingId
                        select bla.BuildingBool;

    //Is the buildingBool false? 
    if (!currentBool.First())
    {
        var currentBuildingDefine = from BuildingDefineTable in _bDefine
                                                    where BuildingDefineTable.buildingId == ((BuildingTable)((ListView)sender).SelectedItem).Id
                                                    select BuildingDefineTable;


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DefineBuilding(currentBuildingDefine));
    }    
    else
    {
        //Do something here. 
    }           

}
//No content in buildingDefineTable
else
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new DefineBuilding(new IEnumerable<_bDefine> bDefineTable ));
}
```

The if sentence works fine, however I am not able to pass an empty list of the table, whenever the database does not contain any information in the table.

This is my constructor:

```
public DefineBuilding(IEnumerable<BuildingDefineTable> bDefineTable)
{
    if (bDefineTable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    BindingContext = bDefineTable;
    //More code here
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: `new List<BuildingDefineTable>()` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var x = new DefineBuilding(Enumerable.Empty<BuildingDefineTable>());
```

Comment: Trivial side note: in .NET 4.6 there's also `Array.Empty<T>()` that works very similarly, and can be used in multiple similar scenarios (including things that need `IList<T>`)

Comment: Is it not giving compile error ` CS0308: The non-generic type 'Enumerable' cannot be used with type arguments` ?

Comment: @amit You probably wrote `Enumerable<something>`... It is `Enumerable.Empty<something>`

Comment: :-). Code changes fast. Thanks @xanatos